# Should the end-of-the-world tag be a synonym?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have synonym tags [end-times](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/end-times) and [apocalyse](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apocalyse) that correctly are synonyms of [eschatology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eschatology). However [end-of-the-world](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/end-of-the-world) doesn't seem to be a synonym. Should it be? Would someone like to make it one?

Answer (score 2):

Done.

I merged the existing tags and made a synonym.